# Are the expressions (!b) and (b==false) equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, boolean, logical-operators

Given that b is a boolean variable, are the expressions (!b) and (b==false) the same?

Here's where I'm at so far with this question:

- !b -- returns a [FALSE response if b is true] or a [TRUE response if
  b is false].
- Declaring a boolean variable, 'b', in this case, would set it to
  true, therefore making !b return false.

I suppose all I need to complete the question is to know whether or not b is initially true, which I assume it to be?

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can clear this up for me?

EDIT:
This is a question from my tutor. I am asked to decide if this statement is true or false:
"The expressions (!b) and (b==false) are equivilaent, where b is a boolean variable"

Here is here extremelly helpful cryptic clue when I asked for some help:

The situation with !b is that these expressions should provide the same result for all values of b in order for the statement to be correct. Ie if b is false, then both expressions give the same result and if b is true then both expressions give the same result. You need to look at both expressions.

Comment: Depends on the language. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent in "sane" languages :-) (let's say **Java**, C++, C#)

In Javascript if `b` can only be `true` or `false`, it is correct (but beware! `if (!null)` is true, `if (null == false)` is false. The same for `undefined`)

Be aware that not all languages use `!` for `NOT` and `==` for `EQUALS`. For example in C you would probably use `int` instead of `bool` and `FALSE` instead of `false`, but the result would be the same (but note that in C, non-zero is "true")

Comment: Language is discovered to be Java.

Answer (score 5):

yes, but good style mandates using `!b` rather than `b == false`

Comment: I love it when I see `if (someBoolean == true)`. Makes me want to kill.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will bear that in mind, I don't want Bohemian to murder me for having poor code :) Thanks alot

Comment: @Bohemian And in `C` it would even be a potential source of bugs :-) `if (someInt)` != `if (someInt == TRUE)`

Comment: @xanatos that reminds me one of my most beloved C expressions: `!!b` (to sanitize a "boolean" value in a branch-less way).

Comment: @xanatos The question and my comment is about java, but that's an interesting point about C

Comment: @Bohemian, I still prefer: `if(someBoolean) return true; else return false;`

Comment: @Bohemian I saw `if (!someBooleanExpressionThatCanBeEasilySimplifiedUsingDeMorgansRules) return false; else return true;`. I was really close to go to jail for murder after reading that code xD